# Need to move rows from form generated sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have a survey sheet that I need my team to see once but after that I want the rows my team sets as "Closed" to an archive sheet. In the past for other sheets I have used this script but it doesn't seem to work on the form linked sheet. After researching I found that you can't CUT from a form linked sheet but you can remove rows, my theory is that the script is trying to cut and that is why is not working. What would a "Copy" and delete aproach would be?

```
    function onEdit(event) {
  // assumes source data in sheet named Needed
  // target sheet of move to named Acquired
  // test column with yes/no is col 4 or D
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();
  var sheets = ["Form Responses", "Input"];
  if(sheets.includes(s.getName()) && r.getColumn() == 1 && r.getValue() == "Closed / Move to Archive") {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Archive");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  }
}
```

Highly appreciate any help

Comment: KIndly share a sample spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I had imagine the issue was the

```
moveTo(target)
```

I changed it to

```
copyTo(target)
```

and now it works properly

Answer (score 0):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sh = e.range.getSheet();
  var sheets = ["Form Responses", "Input"];
  if(sheets.includes(sh.getName()) && e.range.columnStart == 4 && e.value == "Closed") {
    var tsh = e.source.getSheetByName("Archive");
    var tgt = tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1, 1, sh.getLastColumn()).copyTo(tgt);
    sh.deleteRow(e.range.rowStart);
  }
}
```

My Form Response Sheet:

[image]

Archive Sheet:

[image]

Comment: For some reason this is not working on my end. I tried recreating your sheet too but wouldn't run properly here is my test.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hwOGJaW2PnYLPWSgQpoT5s7j_t2IgjKAyV5SnsA1XrY/edit?usp=sharing